# Calculating expectation and variance of a random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I was trying to solve an exercise about derived random variables, but I am stuck on deriving the boundaries to calculate expectation and variance.

> The random variable $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda= 1/2$. Furthermore, define $Y= 1−2X$. Calculate $E(Y)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

[This is what I came up with for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1siCD.png).

It would be much appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: Well, for any distribution $Z$, and constants $a,b$, what is $E[aZ+b]$ in terms of $E[Z]$?  What is $Var[aZ+b]$ in terms of $Var[Z]$?

Comment: @lulu Thanks so much! i think i figured it out. I forgot about those formulas.

Comment: Can someone please also upvote my question, because right now i can't post any more questions because of the downvote...

Comment: Please try to typeset math here using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$\Bbb{E} (a + bX)$ and $\text{Var}(a+bX)$ can be found in terms of $\Bbb{E}(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ respectfully. This comes from the linearity of expectation.

Deriving the first formula, we have $$\Bbb{E}(a+bX) = \int_{- \infty}^\infty f(x)(a+bx) \, dx $$

$$\Bbb{E}(a+bX) =  \underbrace{a \int_{- \infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx}_{= a} \,+  \underbrace{ b \int_{- \infty}^\infty x f(x) \, dx \, }_{=b \Bbb{E}(X)}$$

$$\Bbb{E}(a+bX) = a + b\Bbb{E}(X)$$

You may now use $a=1$ and $b=-2$ to solve for the mean of $Y$

A similar process can be used to derive the variance formula (and it is perhaps easier now that you can apply linearity of expectation)